# Закрытие приложения в фоновом режиме на PyQt5 + Selenium

Tags: python, pyqt5, selenium

Столкнулся с проблемой с закрытием приложения после принудительного закрытия браузера. После этого, если закрыть окно приложения, то оно продолжает работать в фоновом режиме.

Пробовал использовать разные методы, кнопку создавал даже отдельную - ничего не помогло.
Сами методы:

```
    def threadexit(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.exit)
        t1.start()

    def exit(self):
        QApplication.processEvents()
```

```
    def threadexit(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.exit)
        t1.start()

    def exit(self):
        QApplication.exit()
```

```
self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

Так же в функции с selenium есть `time.sleep(3600)`. Предполагаю, что именно из-за этого программа на mac os работает в фоновом режиме.

И собственно сам вопрос: как можно закрыть программу так, чтобы она не работала в фоновом режиме? И если это из-за функции задержки, то как ее можно заменить?

Собственно функциональная часть кода:

```
    def thread1(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.start)
        t1.start()
        
    def save(self):
        proxy = self.LineProxy.text()
        lproxy = self.LineLProxy.text()
        pproxy = self.LinePProxy.text()
        loginru = self.LineRuLogin.text()
        passwordru = self.LineRuPassword.text()
        if proxy == '':
            pass
        else:
            with open('logpas.txt', 'w+') as f:
                f.write(proxy)
                f.write('\n')
                f.write(lproxy)
                f.write('\n')
                f.write(pproxy)
                f.write('\n')
                f.write(loginru)
                f.write('\n')
                f.write(passwordru)

    def start(self):
        proxy = self.LineProxy.text()
        lproxy = self.LineLProxy.text()
        pproxy = self.LineProxy.text()
        loginru = self.LineRuLogin.text()
        passwordru = self.LineRuPassword.text()
        with open('logpas.txt', 'r+') as f:
            a = f.read().split('\n')[0:5]
        q = []
        for i in range(len(a)):
            b = a[i]
            q.append(b)
        if proxy != q[0] and proxy != lproxy:
            url = 'https://rutracker.org/'
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)
            driver.get(url)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            keyboard.write(lproxy)
            keyboard.send('tab')
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            keyboard.write(pproxy)
            keyboard.send('enter')
            vhod = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Вход').click()
            login = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'top-login-uname')
            login.send_keys(loginru)
            password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'top-login-pwd')
            password.send_keys(passwordru)
            password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(3600)
            driver.quit()
        elif q[0] == '':
            pass
        else:
            url = 'https://rutracker.org/'
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={q[0]}')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)
            driver.get(url)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            keyboard.write(q[1])
            keyboard.send('tab')
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            keyboard.write(q[2])
            keyboard.send('enter')
            vhod = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Вход').click()
            login = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'top-login-uname')
            login.send_keys(q[3])
            password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'top-login-pwd')
            password.send_keys(q[4])
            password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(3600)
            driver.quit()
```

Comment: Вызвать принудительно driver.quit();

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467336

Comment: На самом деле можно время от времени спрашивать driver.getWindowHandle() и если возникло исключение, значит браузер закрыли вручную. Можно завершать thread

Comment: @Виктор Как это можно реализовать? Не совсем понимаю, чтобы при этом окно не закрывалось автоматически

Comment: @S.Nick Из представленного там Вами кода я не понимаю что именно может подойти мне

Comment: смотрите все строки, в которых в том или ином виде присутствует сочетание букв `thread`

Comment: @OtetsValerian не важно как закрыли окно,  если окна нет -  driver.getWindowHandle() -> возникнет исключение, В нитке делаете это driver.getWindowHandle(), и если исключение, то return из нитки

Comment: @S.Nick Все равно ничего не дало

Comment: driver.close()
driver.quit()
QApplication.exit()

Comment: Ещё не понятно зачем Вы нитки запускаете и какие

Comment: @Виктор Это работает лишь после завершения остановки программы, а мне надо, так сказать, экстренное завершение

Comment: @Виктор Thread использую для того, чтобы программа не зависала при попытке закрыть приложение до окончания сна

Comment: Закрыли браузер ручками, но QApplication -то работает. У него кнопка закрыть есть и событие на закрыть. Не понимаю чего-то...

Comment: @Виктор пробовал вставить при вызове основной функции в thread, но не работает

Comment: Так Вы нитку прибивайте при выходе тоже. Выставляйте глобальную переменную flgStop = true, а в нитке проверяйте её. Ещё: All windows related to driver instance will quit - driver.quit()

Comment: " пробовал вставить при вызове основной функции в thread," - при чём тут thread? Я про кнопку закрыть писал flgStop = true driver.quit() QApplication.exit(). А в нитке проверяем if flgStop: return После return нитка завершится

Comment: def run():
    while True:
        print('thread running')
        global stop_threads
        if stop_threads:
            break
 
stop_threads = False
t1 = threading.Thread(target = run)
t1.start()
time.sleep(1)
stop_threads = True
t1.join()
print('thread killed')

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, чтобы нагляднее было видно все как у меня устроена программа

Comment: В def start оберните всё в try driver=None ... except ... finally и показывайте qmessagebox c ошибкой. А судя по вашему коду, thread завершается всегда. finnaly: if driver is not None: driver.quit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема в time.sleep(3600), поток спит и закроется только когда проснется. Поэтому большую задержку разбиваем на кучу мелких с проверкой закрыто ли окно браузера. Мне понравилось предложение [Federico Rubbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685330/python-selenium-detect-when-the-browser-is-closed#:%7E:text=I%20would%20suggest%20using%3A), в котором следят за log журналом драйвера - когда там появиться сообщение о  закрытии браузера.
Пример работы сделал на tkinter, но я думаю особого труда не составит перенести на pyqt5. Основу программы взял [отсюда](https://pythonru.com/uroki/asinhronnoe-prilozhenie-ch-1-tkinter-15#:%7E:text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0.-,%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85,-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA).

```
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Создаем окно с кнопкой.
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = tk.Button(self, command=self.start_action, text="Запуск selenium")
        self.button.pack(padx=50, pady=50)
        self.driver = None
        self.check = None
        self.flag = False

# Запускаем дополнительный поток для selenium.
    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_selenium)
        thread.start()
        self.check_thread(thread)

# Делаем активной кнопку только после завершения потока
    def check_thread(self, thread):
        if thread.is_alive():
            self.check = self.after(500, lambda: self.check_thread(thread))
        else:
            self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def run_selenium(self):
        print("Запуск selenium...")
        url = r"https://ya.ru/"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        self.driver.set_window_position(500, 100)
        self.driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.flag = True
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Закройте окно браузера")

# Запускаем "ручной" сон с периодической - два раза в секунду - проверкой не закрыто ли окно браузера
        time_stop = 10  # 3600
        time_start = time.time()
        while self.flag:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if time.time() - time_start < time_stop:
                if self.driver.get_log('driver'):
                    print(self.driver.get_log('driver'))
                    if self.driver.get_log('driver')[-1][
                        'message'] == "Unable to evaluate script: no such window: target window already closed\nfrom unknown error: web view not found\n":
                        self.driver.quit()
                        self.flag = False
                        print("Браузер закрыт пользователем!")
            else:
                self.driver.quit()
                self.flag = False
                print("Действие selenium завершено, без воздействия потусторонних сил!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Если при появлении в терминале надписи "Закройте окно браузера" вы закроете окно, то поток завершится не дожидаясь окончания заданного времени, а если подождете 10(3600) секунд, то процесс завершиться по времени.

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли